# Proving $f(x)$ attains $\max$ or $\min$ when $f(x)\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Suppose $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous such that $f(x)\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$. Prove that $f$ attains either a maximum or a minimum.

My attempt at the question :

Given $\epsilon > 0 \ \ \exists \ \alpha > 0$ such that
$\ |f(x)| < \epsilon\ \ \ \forall \ \ \  \ |x| > \alpha$

Now, when  $\ \ x \in [-\alpha,\ \alpha] $, by the Extreme value theorem, since $f(x)$ is a continuous function on a closed interval, it attains a maximum (say $ M$) and a minimum (say $m$).

I am stuck at this part. I think the way to move forward is by using the fact that we can make $ \epsilon $ as small as possible. But I don't know how to prove that it will surely attain a maximum or a minimum or both.

Comment: Can it attain only a maxima but not a minima and vice-versa? Is there any such example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically done. Here are 2 proofs:

WLOG assume f is not a constant. For every ε we can find an α such that for all x outside of (-α,α), |f(x)| is ε-small.

Since f is not constant it has a supremum S and infimum I over the whole space with S≠I. Since f is bounded, S and I are not infinite. Since S≠I, at least one is not zero. Choose ε small enough so that max(|S|,|I|)>ε.
we then know that there is α such that |f(x)| < ε for all |x|>α, so we only have to maximise/minimise the function on the compact set [-α,α] which we can do by EVT. Either the max is S or the min is I; this proves the result.

Alternatively, choose $\alpha$ minimally (as an infimum) and assume without loss $f$ is not constant. Suppose for a contradiction that $f$ does not achieve its sup and also does not achieve its inf. If $M\geq\varepsilon$ then M is a global maximum and if $m\leq-\varepsilon$ then m is a global minimum. So the only way for this to happen is if $m$ and $M$ are in $(-ε,ε)$; this leads to a contradiction as ε→0. (see chat/comments for details)

Comment: So, in this proof have you proved the existence of _both_ max and min? Because if f(x) = 2exp(-x^2), then min does not exist.

Comment: no, I only proved it either has a minimum or a maximum. The opposite of this statement, which is 'has neither a min nor a max' leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Have edited the wording to make it clearer.

Comment: So, does choosing alpha minimally mean that if even if x is slightly less that alpha, |f(x)| will become >= epsilon? If yes, then I think I understand. Are you implying that if both m and M are in (-eps,+eps), then you can choose an alpha less than the old alpha which still satisfies the constraints (upto where the function achieves max or min, whichever |x| is larger) if I'm not wrong? Is that it?

Comment: Correction to the above comment : "**|x|** is slightly less than alpha"

Comment: Almost, it means 'if you use $\tilde{\alpha} < \alpha$ then you can find an $x ∈ [-\tilde{\alpha},\tilde{\alpha}]$ such that $|f(x)|\geq ε$'. This value $f(x)$ should then be either the minimum or maximum of $[-\alpha,\alpha]$, but it isn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17833/discussion-between-bhuvan-agrawal-and-calvin-khor).

Comment: @CalvinKhor, but should it not be proved that f(x) will attain S or I? f is certainly squeezed between them but will it attain either of the two values?

Comment: @Koro of course one of them is attained, and this is proved above at the application of EVT with the choice of epsilon.