# Trouble in proving that a continuous function vanishing at $\pm\infty$ attains at least its maximum or minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $f:R\to R$ be a function continuous on $R$. Let $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x)=0$ 
 Then I have to show that $f$ :$\;$

$1)$ is bounded on $R$ and

$2)$ attains at least its maximum or minimum on $R$. 
I tried to prove the above as follows: 
For $1)$: Since $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}f(x)=0$. Let $\alpha\gt 0$ be such that $\forall x\gt \alpha: |f(x)|\lt1$. Similarly, let $\beta\lt 0$ be such that $\forall x\lt \beta: |f(x)|\lt 1$. By Boundedness
theorem on $[\alpha,\beta]$,$\;\exists M\gt 0$: $|f(x)|\le M$  $\;\;\forall x\in [\alpha,\beta]$ ,$\;$therefore $\;$$ |f(x)|\le sup(M,1)$ $\forall x \in R$. Hence $f$ is bounded on $R$. 
For $2)$: By maximum-minimum theorem of continuous functions on $[\alpha, \beta]$, $f$ attains its maximum and minimum values on $[\alpha, \beta]$. How do I extend the concept of maximum-minimum theorem  from $[\alpha, \beta]$ to $R$? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970324/proving-fx-attains-max-or-min-when-fx-to0-as-x-to-infty?rq=1

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Thanks a lot. In that answer I need one clarification:"Since f is not constant it has a supremum S and infimum I over the whole space with S≠I". From what I understand from this is that since $|f(x)|\le sup(M,1) \forall x \in R$ hence, $-sup(M,1)\le f(x) \le sup(M,1)$ and hence inf I and sup S exist (by completeness property of real nos.) Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @JohnOmielan. Thanks a lot. In that answer, I need one clarification though which I have mentioned above.

Comment: @Koro Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy. I have doubts in that proof. That answer shows $f$ to be bounded but it does not talk about $f$ attaining maximum or minimum. In particular, the post says: "we only have to maximise/minimise the function on the compact set [-α,α] which we can do by EVT. Either the max is S or the min is I." I don't understand why. Suppose, maximum value attained by $f$ on the compact set is $M$, it may be less than max(|S|,|I|), in which case we cannot ascertain $f$ attains it maximum value?

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide a different approach from those in the links.

One knows that the real line $\Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to the open segment $(-1,1)$, e.g. via stereographic projection.

Thus any continuous function $f$ defined over the real line can be seen as a continuous function $\bar f$ on $(-1,1)$. The conditions that 
$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=N^-$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=N^+$ translate to
$\lim_{x\to-1}\bar f(x)=N^-$ and $\lim_{x\to1}\bar f(x)=N^+$ respectively and thus such function can be extended to a function with domain the closed interval $[-1,1]$.

But the closed interval $[-1,1]$ is compact and thus $\bar f$ has a maximum and a minimum.

Now assume that $N^-=N^+=0$, i.e $\bar f(-1)=\bar f(1)=0$. If so, either the function $\bar f$ is constantly $0$, or the maximum or minimum are attained at points in the open interval $(-1,1)$.